# Compiling and using a library with dependencies in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm trying to use a library (libtmx) that I've compiled that has another library as a dependency (libxml2) that I've also compiled, but when I'm trying to compile the Visual Studio solution that uses the first library (libtmx) I'm getting errors and I don't know what to do...

The documentation for libTMX can be found here: https://libtmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

This is the process I go through...

**Building libxml2**
*(From inside the win32 folder in extracted libxml2 source)*

Configuration

```
> cscript configure.js compiler=msvc prefix=C:\Development\libxml2\install include=C:\Development\libxml2\include lib=C:\Development\libxml2\lib debug=yes iconv=no ftp=no python=no http=no html=no c14n=no legacy=no
```

I could probably remove move stuff from the library, but I'll worry about that later.

**Compilation**

`nmake /f Makefile.msvc`

**Installation**

`nmake /f Makefile.msvc install`

This produces three folders in the installation path; bin, include and lib.

**Building libTMX**

Inside the downloaded source, I make a folder called *build*, step into it and run:

`> cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32`

I edit the generated file CMakeCache.txt and set the following:

```
LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:\Development\libxml2\install\include
LIBXML2_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:\Development\libxml2\install\lib\libxml2.lib
```

I delete all generated files, except for CMakeCache.txt, and run the command again in order to use the updated values.

Then I...

Open the generated .sln -> Right click tmx in solution explorer -> Properties ->
C/C++ -> General -> I add the folder that contains the folder with libxml2 headers.

Right click tmx -> Build -> It builds tmx.lib.

I open the Visual Studio solution that will use the tmx-library, then...

Right click the solution in solution explorer -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General ->
I add the folder that contains the .h files for the tmx library in *Additional Include Directories*.

Linker -> General -> I add the folder where the generated tmx.lib exists to *Additional Library Directories*.

Linker -> Input -> I add tmx.lib -> OK -> right click solution -> build. It then generates 22 similar looking errors, for example:

```
tmx.lib(tmx_xml.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__xmlFreeTextReader referenced in function _parse_template_document
```

I think that's everything.
Any ideas?

Comment: Static libraries are really nothing more than archives of object files. Linking with a static library is similar to linking with the individual object files themselves. As such, all dependencies of a static library needs to be explicitly linked as well, the static library doesn't in itself have the information about it.

Comment: So if project A uses library B, which depends on library C, I have to add the same "include" folders and link to the same C.lib file as lib B needs to do in order for project A to compile?

Comment: You don't need to add the include directories, those are only used for compilation and not linking. But you have to link with C.lib as well.